# How to get Open AI GPT-3.5-turbo and grain access to provide requests

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

sorry for silly question, but i am gave up. How to got model `Open AI GPT-3.5-turbo`? On official web page i found a pricing, but i cant choose and buy what i want. i just found a request form where i need to write company info like: web-page, zip, etc. But i am a single developer and i just want to try this model.

Because when i try to send request like this, just for check, i faced with 401 error, which mean blocked access(i don't have tokens for GPT response)

```
public static void checkResponse() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/davinci-codex/completions")
            .header("Authorization", "Bearer MY_API")
            .build();
    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        if (response.code() == 200) {
            System.out.println("API key has the necessary permissions.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("API key does not have the necessary permissions.");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Request failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```